# Excel: Removing whitespaces from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to create a macro to format a copied table from a specific external source, problem is, some cells appear to be filled from the right to left and the remaining space to the left with spaces:

```
"              1.12" - This is an example of said cell."
```

What I am looking for is a solution to transform the cell value into `"1.12"`.

I have tried using Substitute and Trim functions in excel but those do not solve my problem, any VBA suggestions or similar would be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: How does `Trim` not solve the issue here? It absolutely should

Comment: Are you sure that the characters at the start (and/or end) of string are **White Space** characters?

Comment: If they're a mixture of special characters and white space you could use `RegEx` to identify the bits you need

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Trim`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) function.

*I know you said in your question, that it doesn't work, but it absolutely should*

Removes any leading or trailing whitespaces of the string.
You can of course pass the reference of `Range.Value / Range.Value2` to it instead of the a speicifc `"string2"`

---

> Keep in mind, `Trim` has a `ByVal` reference to the argument. In other
>   words, it will not change the `Range.Value` by itself. So if you were
>   willing to change that, then:

```
Range("A1").Value = Trim(Range("A1").Value) ' "1.12" - Etc..
```

would result the in entire string without whitespaces on left or right. If you only want to return `"1.12"` (I found it kind of unclear from your question, then we'll need to use `InStr()` and `Left()` as well:

This procedure wll run through all the cells in selected column and change them to desired result:

```
Private Sub toCategory(ByVal columnIndex as Long)

  Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Your Sheet Name") ' change me <-
  Dim lr as Long
  Dim cell as Range
  Dim searchrange as Range

  lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnIndex).End(xlUp).Row
  Set searchrange = ws.Range(Cells(1, columnIndex), Cells(lr, columnIndex))

  For Each cell in searchrange
    cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value) ' could be done in one step, but for sake of readability
    cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, InStr(, cell.Value, " ") -1) ' returns "1.12"
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Problem with using `Trim` is that we would presume that all characters the start and end of string are **white spaces**. If the first character is not a white space (i.e. special characters), trim will have no affect

Comment: @Zac OP states in his question, that any trailing or leading characters are whitespaces. Also, unless specified otherwise, that's impossible to answer. We can't list here every case possible of wildcards.

Comment: My suspicion is that if OP has already used `Trim` and it didn't work than there might be non-white space characters there even though OP thinks that they are purely because they aren't visible. If that is the case, this can easily be resolved by either using `chr` range or `regular expression`

Comment: @Zac Very well could, though really, I'd still like to think here the questionee is at fault rather than the answer. There really lacks any resemblence of a MCVE, result received or anything. Wihout such details included, we can only speculate why a certain operation didn't work as intended (or better put, as OP intended). Furthermore, my procedure trims the leading and trailing whitespaces and returns the substring upon first occurance of `" "` so I think it can be a close representation of what OP could be trying to achieve, whitespace or not

Comment: But as said, without further specifcation by OP, we can only speculate what is the optimal approach. Very well might be regexp, but might as well be completely unnecessary

Comment: Completely agree, I think the lack of information is where most of the queries here fall short. But like you said, we can only go by what OP provides

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in cell A1 then try this formula in B1

> =TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160)," ")))

Comment: Not sure if `Substitute` is a good option here. It will potentially remove any spaces from within the actual string as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use Find and Replace, both in a macro format, or manually depending on how often you would have to do this.

When using replace, highlight one of the blank spaces and copy it, then use the inbuilt excel replace feature (make sure you expand on the options and un-select match entire cell contents) then paste the "blank space" into the find box and leave the replace box empty.

*CTRL+F will open the find menu, and click on the tab for replace menu.

Comment: copy and paste data into new worksheet
find and replace
(there could be a new line CR + LF as a leading space. You can try this as well.)
 -> null
space -> null
 
->
null